# I have two overlapping divs

Tags: html, css, position

I have two overlapping divs on my site, I can not find the solution. I do not know if it's about positions or not?

```css
#slides {
  position: relative;
  height: 600px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.slide {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

.img_slider {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  border: 1px groove;
}

.showing {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div id="sliderBox" class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <ul id="slides">

        <li class="slide showing"><img class="img_slider" src="./images/bg2.png" />
          <p class="textSlider">Cliquez sur la station de votre choix<br />Si un vélo est disponible le bouton "Effectuer une reservation" s'activera</p>
        </li>
        <li class="slide"><img class="img_slider" src="./images/bg3.png" />
          <p class="textSlider">Pour valider votre réservation, merci de remplir les champs nom et prénom, et effectuer une signature</p>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried to change the position but nothing to do, I searched the answers but none correspond

Comment: looking at your code, i'm gonna assume that the overlapping divs, are `.slide`, why ? because you have `position:absolute` on both of them and that takes them out of the document flow, which means they won't care for other elements even each other,  and you positioned them exactly the same with the `left: 0px;
  top: 0px;`

Comment: When you say "I have two overlapping divs in my website" what do you mean exactly and what is the expected behaviour?